# Chave Estrangeira Circular

Tags: banco-de-dados, arquitetura-de-software, modelo-relacional, chave-estrangeira

Frequentemente vejo banco de dados modelados de forma que as chaves estrangeiras fecham uma referência circular, para exemplificar utilizei um modelo com `cidade`,`bairro` e `cliente`. Segue o modelo ER:

[image: Modelo ER]

Entendo que nesse formato, pode haver inconsistência dos dados.

As perguntas são:

**Há alguma documentação que define essa modelagem como certa ou errada?**

***Referência Circular* é o termo correto para definir essa situação?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Há alguma documentação que define essa modelagem como certa ou errada?

O que existe não é certo ou errado, mas sim o modelo ideal para cada aplicação. Em certos casos, a utilização de normalização é ideal para prevenir que sejam geradas inconsistências na base, devido a repetição de dados. Já em outros casos (e.g. Aplicações que respondem em tempo real), a normalização pode ser nociva pois aumenta o número de tabelas consequentemente aumentando o número de `joins` e tornando assim as consultas mais lentas. As vezes é aceitável replicar alguns dados em diferentes tabelas visando otimizar consultas no sistema, mas isso aumenta o risco de geração de inconsistências, e por isso essas decisões precisam ser bem pensadas. No fim das contas é um `trade-off`.

> Referência Circular é o termo correto para definir essa situação?

Esse termo pode ser usado para definir essa situação. O grande risco é quando aplicações que usam o JPA, por exemplo, mapeiam os objetos sem usar `lazy-loading`. Implementando de forma correta o sistema e dependendo dos requisitos da aplicação, esse comportamento cíclico é aceitável.